# SQL where conditions from 2 columns are met

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

*****Question edited*****

#TEMP_TABLE data:
| Serial Number | ORIG | DEST |
| ------------- | ---- | ---- |
| 12345         | CAN  | YOW  |
| 67890         | YYZ  | PEK  |
| 13579         | PEK  | YVR  |
| 24680         | PVG  | YOW  |
| 15764         | YVR  | XIY  |
| 24863         | CTU  | PVG  |

I was able to get my expected results by:

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE
WHERE
(ORIG IN ('PEK','PVG') AND LEFT(DEST,1)<>'Y')
OR
(ORIG NOT IN ('PEK','PVG') AND LEFT(ORIG,1)<>'Y')
OR
(ORIG NOT IN ('PEK','PVG') AND LEFT(ORIG,1)='Y' AND DEST NOT IN ('PEK','PVG'));
```

Expected results:
| Serial Number | ORIG | DEST |
| ------------- | ---- | ---- |
| 12345         | CAN  | YOW  |
| 15764         | YVR  | XIY  |
| 24863         | CTU  | PVG  |

Looking to a different way to achieve the same results by using nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM #TEMP_TABLE
WHERE
(ORIG IN ('PEK','PVG') AND LEFT(DEST,1)<>'Y')
OR
(ORIG NOT IN ('PEK','PVG') AND DEST IN
    (SELECT DEST FROM #TEMP_TABLE
        WHERE LEFT(ORIG,1)='Y' AND DEST NOT IN ('PEK','PVG'))
);
```

But it gives me a different result:
| Serial Number | ORIG | DEST |
| ------------- | ---- | ---- |
| 15764         | YVR  | XIY  |

Comment: "but it's not giving me the correct results.", it's giving you an error, why didn't you tell us that, and included the error message?

Comment: it's giving the results: 12345, 67890, 15764, 24863. but 67890 shouldn't be because it's not meeting criteria of LEFT(ORIG,1)=Y AND DEST NOT IN (PEK,PVG)

Comment: The SQL in the question does not give the result stated in the comment. (It would return only 15764 if you simply added the missing quotes to avoid a syntax error.) Edit the question rather than putting details in a comment. BTW - example data should be supplied as text. Only use images when visual content is important.

Comment: Can `orig` or `dest` be null?

Comment: I edited my question, but not sure why the table is not displayed - I had it displayed in HTML in preview when I edited.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the the characters in NOT IN clause should require 'PEK','PVG' along with your other NOT IN statement.  And the Y would probably need 'Y'.

```
SELECT [SerialNumber] FROM TESTTABLE
WHERE ORIG NOT IN ('PEK','PVG')
AND LEFT(ORIG,1)='Y' AND DEST NOT IN ('PEK','PVG')
```